# Is this case for debounce correct?

Tags: javascript, throttling, debouncing

I practiced a debounce on bigfrontend, there is an example in the stem of the question, each dash represents the waiting time, the question is about the following

[image]

The question is https://bigfrontend.dev/problem/implement-basic-debounce

My understanding is that each time the event timer is executed will be retimed, then for the E event, why the F event is not executed, while the G event is executed, is my understanding of the problem is wrong?

I want to know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: `F` is not executed because there is less than three `-` between `E` and `F`

Comment: Side note: the grammar of that challenge description is inferior. Not a good sign of what the general quality is of their material.

Comment: @Konrad But why is D triggered? The number of - between C and D is also less then three

Comment: It's about how much time passed after the last event. There are 6 `-` between `D` and `E`. If more than 2 `-`  passed it should be triggered. I think you mixed up debounce with throttle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the graphical representation is misleading. The letters in that representation should not take extra horizontal space as if a "dash" time unit had passed. So it would be better represented like this:

```
─A─B─C─ ─D─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─E─ ─F─G─ ─ ─ ─ (without debouncing)
─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─D─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─G─ (with    debouncing)
         │     ▲           │     ▲
         └─────┘           └─────┘    
            +3                +3
```

So now we see that G is triggered **3 dashes** later than in the original scenario. And that makes sense, because there were no other events happening after G was scheduled that would have overruled it. All other events (A, B, C, E, F) were overruled (replaced) by a subsequent event that occurred sooner than 3 dash units later:

- A was replaced by B because B occurred 1 dash later
- B was replaced by C because C occurred 1 dash later
- C was replaced by D because D occurred 2 dashes later
- D was fired, because nothing occurred during the next 3 dashes.
- E was replaced by F because F occurred 2 dashes later
- F was replaced by G because G occurred 1 dash later
- G was fired, because nothing occurred during the next 3 dashes.

Comment: If you have a new question, then please post it as a new question. If however you feel something is not clear in my answer to the current question on debouncing, please let me know.

Comment: The correct understanding would be that ABCD doesn't take up the length of the dash right, so there should be two dashes between AC?

Comment: The number of dashes is as you posted it. Yes, two dashes between A and C.

Comment: Oh my god, I always thought each event took up a dash, I see what the problem is, thanks!